# How does sharepoint recognize a file type?

Tags: sharepoint, moss

How does sharepoint identify a file type? For example, SharePoint will not allow you to upload executable files. Suppose if i rename a file extension from .exe to say, .doc, will the sharepoint allow the upload of this file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sharepoint recognize file types using their extensions.

If you are worried about users spreading malicious application/code in your Sharepoint Sites. I suggest you to take a look at [Microsoft Forefront For Sharepoint](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/sharepoint/en/us/default.aspx).

You can modify the excluded extension list under **Central Administration > Operations > Blocked File Types**.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two ways to identify file types. A naive approach is to check the extension. A more secure approach would be to examine the bits of the file and see what type the file is as many file types have a few bits ([magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number)) in the header that identify the format.

Depending on how SharePoint checks the file, that will determine how you can cheat the system.

Comment: That is my doubt actually. Does Sharepoint go by the extension? Or does it use the magic numbers?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint itself isn't very smart and relies on file extensions, so renaming files will get around it.

Forefront for SharePoint does do file inspection, so should be on your must-have list for anything external facing (and internal if you allow staff to install/run unknown software).

You can manage the blocked file extension list in the Central Admin in the Operations/Blocked File Types section.  Note: this is per webapp!